# Polar coordinates injective intervals, help.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, parametrization

> Polar coordinates in plane. Consider the following open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$:
>
> $M=\mathbb{R}^2-\{0,0\}$.
>
> Let $\psi:\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}\to M\\(\rho\cos(\theta),\rho\sin(\theta))$

**a)**

i)$\psi$ is of $C^\infty$ class

ii)$\psi$ is not injective

iii)$\det\nabla(\psi,(\rho\theta))=\rho^2>0$, so $\psi$ is an immersion

**b)**

Let:

$I_1=]-\pi,\pi[,\:\:\:A_1=\mathbb{R}_+\times I_1,\:\:\:\psi:A_1\to M,(\rho,\theta)\to\psi(\rho,\theta)\\I_2=]0,2\pi[,\:\:\:A_2=\mathbb{R}_+\times I_2,\:\:\:\psi:A_2\to M,(\rho,\theta)\to\psi(\rho,\theta)$.

Therefore:

i)$\psi(A_1)=U_1=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(x,0):x\leqslant 0\}$ is an open set of $M$.

ii)$\psi(A_2)=U_2=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(x,0):x\geqslant 0\}$ is an open set of $M$.

**Questions:**

**1)** Why is (0,0) excluded from $\mathbb{R}^2$? If I take $\psi((0,0))=0$. What is the problem? Why $M=\mathbb{R}^2-\{0,0\}$?

**2)** I do not understand $\psi(A_1)=U_1=\mathbb{R}^2-\{(x,0):x\leqslant 0\}$.
Why is the negative x axis excluded? In the interval $]-\pi,\pi[$, $cos(\theta)$ can be zero. Why exclude the negative part of the x-axis?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The point $(0,0)$ is excluded because $\psi((0,\theta))=(0,0)$ for each $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, while we would like that $\psi$ is injective as a map defined on $\mathbb{R}^{+} \times ]0,2\pi[$ (or similar intervals with length $2\pi$, so you can consider for example $]-\pi,\pi[$, if you prefer).

2) The negative axis $\{x\leq 0\}$ is the image of $\mathbb{R}^+ \times \{\pi+2k\pi\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$, but $\pi+2k\pi\notin I_1$ for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. A similar argument can be used for $A_2$.

Comment: $\cos(\frac{-4\pi}{3})=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{-4\pi}{3}\in ]-\pi,\pi[$. How can $x\leqslant 0$ be excluded?

Comment: Actually $-\frac{4\pi}{3}\notin ]-\pi,\pi[$. However, I think I understand your mistake: look, the set you are excluding is $\{x\leq 0, y=0\}$, namely the half-line made of pairs of real numbers which the first coordinate is not positive and the second coordinate is zero. In fact the only $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ for which their images are on this half-line are actually $\pi+2k\pi$, that are not included in $]-\pi,\pi[$.